# How to correctly chain Mono/Flux calls

Tags: spring, spring-boot, spring-webflux, reactive-streams

I'm having trouble with understanding how to achieve my goal with reactive approach.
Let's assume that I have a Controller, that will return Flux:

```
@PostMapping(value = "/mutation/stream/{domainId}", produces = MediaType.TEXT_EVENT_STREAM_VALUE)
public Flux<Mutation> getMutationReactive(@RequestBody List<MutationRequest> mutationRequests, @PathVariable Integer domainId) {
    return mutationService.getMutations(mutationRequests, domainId);
}
```

In service, currently with .subscribeOn(Schedulers.boundedElastic()), because it calls for a blocking code that is wrapped into a Callable.

```
public Flux<Mutation> getMutations(List<MutationRequest> mutationRequests, int domainId) {
        return Flux.fromIterable(mutationRequests)
                .subscribeOn(Schedulers.boundedElastic())
                .flatMap(mutationRequest -> getMutation(mutationRequest.getGameId(), mutationRequest.getTypeId(), domainId));
}
```

getMutation() with blocking calls, currently wrapped into a Callable:

```
 private Mono<Mutation> getMutation(int gameId, int typeId, int domainId) {
        return Mono.fromCallable(() -> {
            Mutation mutation = mutationProvider.findByGameIdAndTypeId(gameId, typeId).block(); // mutationProvider.findByGameIdAndTypeId() returns Mono<Mutation>
            if (mutation == null) {
                throw new RuntimeException("Mutation was not found by gameId and typeId");
            }
            State state = stateService.getStateByIds(mutation.getId()), domainId).blockFirst(); //stateService.getStateByIds() returns Mono<State>
            if (state == null || state.getValue() == null) {
                log.info("Requested mutation with gameId[%s] typeId[%s] domainId[%s] is disabled. Value is null.".formatted(gameId, typeId, domainId));
                return null;
            }
            mutation.setTemplateId(state.getTemplateId());
            return (mutation);
        });

    }
```

How do I approach the getMutation() function to use reactive streams, instead of using .block() methods inside a Callable?
Basically, I first need to retrieve Mutation from DB -> then using ID of mutation, get its state from other service -> then if state and its value are not null, set templateId of state to mutation and return, or  return null.

I've tried something like this:

```
private Mono<Mutation> getMutation(int gameId, int typeId, int domainId) {
    return mutationProvider.findByGameIdAndTypeId(gameId, typeId)
                .flatMap(mutation -> {
                    stateService.getStatesByIds(mutation.getId(), domainId).flatMap(state -> {
                        if (state != null && state.getValue() != null) {
                            mutation.setTemplateId(state.getTemplateId());
                        }
                        //TODO if state/value is null -> need to propagate further to return null instead of mutation...
                        return Mono.justOrEmpty(state);
                    });
                    return Mono.just(mutation);
                });
}
```

But it's obviously incorrect, nothing is subscribed to stateService.getStatesByIds(mutation.getId()), domainId)
AND
I would like to return a null if the retrieved state of mutation or its value are null.

Comment: If it returns a `Mono` already why block? Use the map etc. functions to chain. You also shouldn't return `null` but an empty `Mono` when nothing is there, you can just add the return inside the `if` and outside return an `Mono.empty()`. However wouldn't it be better to write a query that gives you all you need in 1 go, instead of doing a 1+N select thing (you are generating a lot of queries).

Comment: I guess my question description was not fully correct, edited misleading parts. StateService does not make a direct call to DB, it does a lot of other fetching/calculations, so I can't do a single query that gives me everything in one go...

Comment: Regardless of that last comment of mine, the rest still applies.

Comment: With all respect, I know that I need to chain using map/flatMap. My question was -> how to use map functions in this specific example, because I can't wrap my head around it myself.

Comment: Have you read my comment? -> *add the return inside the if and outside return an `Mono.empty()`*

Comment: It doesn't change the fact that inside the first flatMap nothing is subscribed to this publisher:
stateService.getStatesByIds(mutation.getId(), domainId).
So adding those Mono's doesn't help me at all.

Comment: There should nothing be subscribed. In the end that will be the client that is calling your controller that will subscribe to the chain.

Comment: I get an empty result back, when requesting it like that. IntelliJ also points out that 
stateService.getStatesByIds(mutation.getId(), domainId).flatMap()
value is never used as a Publisher.

Comment: Which is, as stated because of your wrong return for which I gave you the solution... Which you fail to apply and read over each time and of-course do a return of that value inside your outer `flatMap` method.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are ignoring the value of the inner `flatMap` hence the warning.

Without trying you need something like this

```
private Mono<Mutation> getMutation(int gameId, int typeId, int domainId) {
    return mutationProvider.findByGameIdAndTypeId(gameId, typeId)
                .flatMap(mutation -> {
                    return stateService.getStatesByIds(mutation.getId(), domainId).flatMap(state -> {
                        if (state != null && state.getValue() != null) {
                            mutation.setTemplateId(state.getTemplateId());
                            return Mono.just(mutation);
                        }
                        return Mono.empty();
                    });
                });
}
```

Although not sure if you could rewrite the outer `flatMap` not to a regular `map` instead and you might want to use `filter` and `defaultIfEmpty` with that as well

```java
private Mono<Mutation> getMutation(int gameId, int typeId, int domainId) {
    return mutationProvider.findByGameIdAndTypeId(gameId, typeId)
                .flatMap(mutation -> {
                    return stateService.getStatesByIds(mutation.getId(), domainId)
    .filter(state -> state != null && state.getValue() != null)
    .flatMap(state -> {
        mutation.setTemplateId(state.getTemplateId());
        return Mono.just(mutation);})
    .defaultIfEmpty(Mono.empty());
}
```

This is just from the top of my head and I have no idea what some of the return types are here (`Flux` or `Mono`) for your own APIs.

Comment: Thank you, that looks like the correct way.